# What schema for an activity / news / timeline feed ? (without friend sytem)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, relationship

i was wondering what would be the best schema to show two different type of contents in a feed. I came up with 2 ways, one used by WP and the other one is what i think should be best but i'm still not sure.

First schema and relations.

- feed

  | id | type | type_id |
- shots

  | id | user_id | title | desc | image | date creation | date update |
- snippet

  | id | user_id | title |desc | url | date creation | date update |

In this case, i would do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM feed
INNER JOIN shots
ON feed.type_id = shots.id 
INNER JOIN snippets
ON feed.type_id = snippets.id
```

And the other schema would be WP type schema

- feed

  | id | user_id | title | desc | image | url | date creation | date update

And only one query without join would be done, BUT all records would be in the same table and potentially if i had other fields i would add columns here, which is not scalable at all.

I could change to the following

- extra

  | id | owner_id | name | value |

  | 1  |      123      | url  | ..... |

  | 2  |      456      | image| ..... |
- feed

  | id | user_id | title | desc | date creation | date update

And eventually i would have the following

```
SELECT *
FROM feed
LEFT JOIN extra
ON feed.id = extra.owner_id
```

Which one is better ? Keep in mind that in future i would have more and more different kind of content (questions, videos, comments, tutorials, posts...)